# Сервис JAX-WS при передаче коллекции вызывает JAXBException

Tags: java, service, коллекции, jax-ws

Пытаюсь при помощи сервиса передать LinkedList из собственных объектов. Сами объекты содержат только примитивные типы, поэтому с ними проблем нет. Но при передаче List возвращает XML вида:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><S:Body>
```

и на этом все. Томакат выдает:

```
javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: class java.util.LinkedList nor any of its super class is known to this context
```

Начитался что JAX-WS не работает с Java коллекциями, но все что советовали не сработало. Что пробовал:

1) Обернуть List в класс, где List будет параметром.

2) Использовать вместо интерфейса List классы ArrayList и LinkedList

3) 1 и 2 вместе

3) Передавать массив объектов. Та же шляпа.

4) На английской версии stackoverflow советовали аннотации перед гэттером возвращающим list:

```
@XmlElementWrapper(name="error_list") 
@XmlElement(name="error")
```

Сервис самый простой:

```
@WebService() 
public class TechnicalSOAP {
   @WebMethod
   public Object technicalMethods(){
      List<Device> devicesList = new LinkedList();
      devicesList.add(new Device);
      return devicesList;
}
```

Объект тоже:

```
public class Device(){
   private Integer id;
   public void setId(Integer id){
      this.id = id;
   }
   public void getId(){
      return this.id;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вернуть "голый" List из веб-метода будет затруднительно, к тому же, обычно это и не требуется. Обычно, веб-сервисы возвращают некий бизнес-объект ответа, в котором, в числе прочих полей можно вернуть также и коллекции. Работающий пример для Вашего случая может быть таким:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "response")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class TechnicalResponse {

  @XmlElementWrapper(name = "devices")
  @XmlElement(name = "device")
  private LinkedList<Device> devicesList;

  public LinkedList<Device> getDevicesList() {
    return devicesList;
  }

  public void setDevicesList(LinkedList<Device> devicesList) {
    this.devicesList = devicesList;
  }
}


@WebService()
@XmlSeeAlso(TechnicalResponse.class)
public class TechnicalSOAP {

  @WebMethod
  public Object technicalMethods() {
    LinkedList<Device> devicesList = new LinkedList<>();
    devicesList.add(new Device());
    TechnicalResponse response = new TechnicalResponse();
    response.setDevicesList(devicesList);
    return response;
  }
}
```

Comment: Работает как часы! Спасибо =)